# CSS navigation with logo in middle of the row

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a navigation menu with 6 items, 3 on the left, 3 on the right with the logo (the logo to be both vertically and horizontally centered)

The problem I am having is the logo looks centered, but not vertically. Also the navigation items are too far apart from the logo and the my navigation items on the right are not in the correct order.

What I am trying to accomplish is to make it look like the screenshots attached.

[image]

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/fa970mnm/2/

```css
.site-footer ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.site-footer ul li a {
  color: #e1c66b;
}

#logo {
  height: 125px;
}

.nav {
  text-align: center;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

@media(min-width:786px) {
  .nav li:nth-child(1),
  .nav li:nth-child(2),
  li:nth-child(3) {
    float: left;
  }
  .nav li:nth-child(4),
  .nav li:nth-child(5),
  li:nth-child(6) {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <img id="logo" src="http://www.jamaicacannabisestates.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/logo.png" />
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/shop/">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="/our-story/">Our Story</a></li>
    <li><a href="/products/">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="/foundation/">Foundation</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably be best suited using a [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) in this situation. You can simply use the following rules for your container `<div>`.

```
#banner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

And you can mess with the `margin-right` rule for the `.element` class I added to change the amount of spacing, or maybe take a look at `justify-content: space-between` from the link above.

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vjw742pn).

Comment: I tried your suggestion, looks off center when I applied it....ill attach a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Why do not you just put the logo between LI?
Just move the logo and improve CSS:

```
.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

Display as 'Inline-block', because 'vertical-align middle' doesnt work with 'inline'.

https://jsfiddle.net/fa970mnm/14/

Answer (score 0):

First move your `logo` to `.nav` as a child.

Then change `.nav li` `inline` to `display: inline-block;`.

Like this

```
.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

***Here is the working Snippet***

```css
.site-footer ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.site-footer ul li a {
  color: #e1c66b;
}

#logo {
  height: 125px;
}

.nav {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/shop/">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="/our-story/">Our Story</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href=""><img id="logo" src="http://www.jamaicacannabisestates.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/logo.png" /></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/products/">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="/foundation/">Foundation</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```